# Isomorphisms and the Fundamental Homomorphism Theorem

Tags: ring-theory, abstract-algebra

Let 
$$
R=\left\{
\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ 0 & a \end{bmatrix}
: a,b∈ℝ\right\}⊂M_2(ℝ)
$$
and 
$$
I=\left\{
\begin{bmatrix} 0 & b \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}:  b∈ℝ\right\}.
$$

Identify the quotient ring $R/I$ by exhibiting a homomorphism whose kernel is $I$.

Ok, I'm just going to be honest. I have no idea how to do this problem. Can someone please help me get it started at least, please. Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Define the map $f\colon R\to \mathbb{R}$ by
$$f\left(\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ 0 & a \end{bmatrix}\right)= a$$
and show it's a ring homomorphism.

Comment: I've seen it used where that kind of an arrow is used. What does that mean though?

Comment: @Dillon It is the symbol for 'mapped to'. So this means that the function $f$ sends that matrix to the value $a$.

Comment: How would I show this is an ideal?

Comment: @Dillon Is it clearer, now?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: try to think about the structure of $R/I$ like the set of all elements in $R$, but with $x = 0$ if $x \in I$.

Comment: I'm not sure how that could help me. Can you expand on that thought please?

Answer (score 0):

Use the above $f$ and the First isomorphism theorem to show that

$R/I$ is isomorphic to the image of $f$, which here happens to be $\mathbb{R}$.